# What is a trade-off?

Tags: phrase-meaning, semantics

What is a trade-off?

Consider a hypotethetical situation: I want to by my fiancee flowers. Her ideal flowers would be blue, have 3 petals, and a beautiful fragrance.

- Flower Shop A sells blue flowers with 20 petals and a beautiful fragrance.
- Flower Shop B sells blue flowers with 3 petals and an unpleasant fragrance.
- Flower Shop C sells red flowers with 3 petals and a beautiful fragrance.

I'm not limited financially, so I can buy flowers from as many shops as I like, but I cannot buy flowers that are blue, have 3 petals, and a beautiful fragrance because they do not exist in that combination (and never will, in this imaginary world).

Does the inability to obtain blue flowers with 3 petals and a beautiful fragrance constitute a trade-off?

I have discussed this with another who insists that this is *not* a trade-off because "all factors are available at the same time", as per the [Merriam-Webster definition of trade-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade-off):

> a balancing of factors all of which are not attainable *at the same time*

*i.e.* one can obtain 3-petal flowers, blue flowers, and fragrant flowers, *at the same time*. It seems that this hinges on taking various definitions of "at the same time" referring to a purely *temporal* relationship, rather than a physical and combinatorial sense. Is there a a better, more technical definition, which encompasses a physical sense of the inter-relatedness of the factors, or is this not an example of a trade-off?

Comment: One of the factors is money.

Comment: what is a multi-factored trade off ?

Answer (score 1):

"Trade-off" wouldn't refer to "the inability to obtain blue flowers with 3 petals and a beautiful fragrance". It would refer to what advantage or set of advantages is gained under one of alternatives while not available under another alternative, where the second alternative has one or more advantages that the first one doesn't have.

One would say that the trade-off from buying flowers from Shop B instead of Shop A is that you'll get flowers with the ideal number of petals, at the expense of the beautiful fragrance you'd have gotten from Shop A. More briefly, in choosing between Shops A and B, there's a trade-off between petal count and fragrance.

I suppose your friend, who might prefer his parrots to have two legs and his cats to have four, would be content to have a parrot with four legs. But, more seriously, there's a difference between your fiancee preferring flowers that are all blue, 3-petaled, and beautifully fragrant, and your fiancee preferring bouquets of flowers where each flower is blue OR has 3 petals OR is beautifully fragrant, independently of the others, with each flower having *at least one* of those qualities. Your case is presumably the former one.